# How to make a animated button in menu (unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a game scene with menu basic options like play, settings and so on but for let this more attractive to the user. 
i want a simple animation for this buttons. 
i don't want a hover or onclick animation i want the buttons to repeat the animation while the user is in the home scene the animation can be color change or the button changing his size or position in the screen (i don't know the right name for this I imagine like a wink effect) 
I don't know if it's helpful but the it's a 2D project

Comment: How are buttons implemented? Are they actual gameobjects under canvas or something drawn from code?

Comment: Give it an animation controller and set its animation?

Comment: they're UI elements inside of the canvas, at the moment i already made the animation (using the animation window). i'm trying to transform in a loop right now because it only work when i put finger or mouse over the button (like hover from css)

Comment: Animate the source image of the `Image` component of that button then play it through code. That cannot be hard to do....

Comment: Go to your animation file in the inspector and make sure that Loop Time is checked.

Comment: @Dtb49 https://imgur.com/a/Igi84

Comment: @darkcode2.0 that is the animator not the animation.

Comment: @dtb49 https://imgur.com/a/VIEwK yeah it is, i only made the animation for the normal state but the others are checked too

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Unity UI (which I think you are), you can just change the transition mode and add an animator to them.

Check out this official Unity tutorial on the subject:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-transitions

Comment: i already see this. but the problem is i want the animation to be infinite, in this video the animation run only in a state (normal, highlighted, pressed)  like if you click the button or if you put the mouse hover the element etc, i want the menu scene to be animated as long as the user stay in menu scene.

Comment: I think that can be done by giving the normal state a looping animation. In the animation file there should be a checkbox that you can check to set it to loop.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out how to animate an image from the animator in the Unity UI. Since that is what OP seems to be asking, I wanted to post my solution for those that are interested. Just attach to a gameobject with animator and image components. Animators can be exchanged and refreshed with the **Reset()** function, and turned off with the **Flush()** function.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;

public class ImageAnimation : MonoBehaviour {

  public float speed;

  private Animator animator;
  private Image image;
  private int curIdx;
  private float curTime;
  private List<Sprite> sprites;
  private bool valid;

  void Awake() {
    image = GetComponent<Image> ();
    Color white = Color.white;
    white.a = 1;
    image.color = white;
    animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    if (animator.runtimeAnimatorController == null) {
      valid = false;
    } else {
      sprites = GetSpritesFromAnimator(animator);
      curIdx = 0;
      curTime = speed;
      valid = true;
    }
  }

  public void Reset(){
    Awake();
  }

  public void Flush(){
    Color white = Color.white;
    white.a = 0;
    image.color = white;
    valid = false;
  }

  void Update () {
     if (valid) {
       curTime -= Time.deltaTime;
       if ( curTime < 0 )
       {
          curTime = speed;
          if (curIdx >= sprites.Count){
            curIdx = 0;
          }
          image.sprite = sprites[curIdx];
          curIdx++;
       }
     }
  }

  #if UNITY_EDITOR
   public static List<Sprite> GetSpritesFromAnimator(Animator anim)
   {
       List<Sprite> _allSprites = new List<Sprite> ();
       foreach(AnimationClip ac in anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
       {
           _allSprites.AddRange(GetSpritesFromClip(ac));
       }
       return _allSprites;
   }

   private static List<Sprite> GetSpritesFromClip(AnimationClip clip)
   {
       var _sprites = new List<Sprite> ();
       if (clip != null)
       {
           foreach (var binding in AnimationUtility.GetObjectReferenceCurveBindings (clip))
           {
               ObjectReferenceKeyframe[] keyframes = AnimationUtility.GetObjectReferenceCurve (clip, binding);
               foreach (var frame in keyframes) {
                   _sprites.Add ((Sprite)frame.value);
               }
           }
       }
       return _sprites;
   }
  #endif
}
```